# Is there any way to convert a array pointer back into a regular array?

Tags: c++

I am trying to pass an array through a function but when I try to get the length of the array it gives me the length of the pointer. Is there any way to convert the array pointer back into a regular array?

```
float arr[] = {10, 9, 8]

void func(float arr[])
{
   // now I want to figure out the size of the array 
   int lenArr = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); // this will get the size of the pointer to the array and not the actual array's size
}
```

Comment: With C-style arrays, always pass the size along with the array, which will decay to a pointer. Or scrap that type and use `std::array`.

Comment: @Immanuel Charles Declare the parameter as having a referenced type. That is pass the array by reference.

Comment: If you must pass in a C-style array (which will be a *pointer* to the first element of the array), also pass in the `std::size_t` size of the number of elements in the array.

Comment: Outside of this function.  How is your array declared and how would you determine its length?

Comment: @sweensih thanks for the suggestion but I dont know the size of the array and std::array needs the size

Comment: @John I declare the array without the size. I determen its length by using this line of code:

`sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);`

Comment: You could use std::array or std::vector instead of an C array altogether or create a std::range parameter from your C array

Comment: Maybe post some code for context.

Comment: Use your calculation to pass the size to the function. As of C++17, `std::array arr{1, 2, 3};` compiles just fine.

Comment: The size calculation only works before passing the array into a function as parameter (that is why some commenters suggested an additional size parameter). Using C arrays is in general not recommended for C++. Especially because of those limitations, which could lead to errors or security issues, if the function accesses the array behind the end. Try std::vector<float>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare the parameter a reference to an array.

```
void func(float (&arr)[10])
{
    // but you have to know the size of the array.
}
```

To get around having to know the size, you can template on size

```
template<int Size>
void func(float (&arr)[Size])
{
    // Now the size of the array is in "Size"
    // So you don't need to calcualte it.
}
```

Comment: One should mention that the size has to be determined/-able at compile time even with the template solution

Comment: @Sebastian True. But also true for the C style array being passed in the OP question.